# Linux ext3 and ext4 files - compatability question

Tags: c++, c, linux, deployment, ubuntu

I have developed (compiled) some (C/C++) applications on my local machine, which has the ext4 file system. I want to deploy the compiled binaries to my server - which has a ext3 file system format.

Can I simply create a package and deploy the binary on the server - or are the file systems incompatable?

BTW, both my local dev machine and the remote server are running Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely can. File system formats are completely irrelevant to binary executable formats. You can transfer files from one system to another with no ill effects.

Of course, if your program has external dependencies (shared libraries) then the other system might not have all that's necessary to run your program -- but that's another problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Usually (if your program doesn't rely on the filesystem format) there should be no problem. The processors however have to be compatible: you cannot run a program compiled for Intel processor on Sparc. (However, Ubuntu seems to run only on Intel-compatibles, right?)